# PDO bindParam bindValue binary data type yii php

Tags: php, pdo, binary, prepared-statement

I am using sql server 2005. data type of a column(id) of a table is binary(16)

when I select it, the result is string. for example, actual value of id is 0x65589D8124FA6348A61757A5A93FE9F2, returned value is 65589D8124FA6348A61757A5A93FE9F2 and its type is string.

now, I'm trying to update the row with bindParam, and putting data type as PDO::PARAM_LOB
finally it does nothing.

please help.

```
 $sql="update _Reference7209 set _Reference7209._Description = 'anything' where _IDRRef = :customer_id";    
        $command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
        $s = "0x65589D8124FA6348A61757A5A93FE9F2";
        $command->bindParam(":customer_id",$s,PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        var_dump($command->execute());
```

it always returns 0

any suggestions

Comment: I don't know SQL Server, but PDO_SQLSRV defines `PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY` as a constant for binary input/output. Have you tried that instead of LOB?

Comment: @deceze yes I tried once, but still no result. thx, anyway